# Site collection search scope - exclude rule for dispform/allitems.aspx

Tags: search, search-scope

I have created a site collection search scope and I am trying to exclude dispform.aspx and allitems.aspx from the search results. The crawl rule at the site collection scope doesn't seem to work with regular expressions. I have tried the below, but not working

```
http://<sitename>/*DispForm.aspx*

http://<sitename>/.*DispForm.aspx*
```

This is with complete path to dispform of a list

```
http://<sitename>/<subsite>/Lists/<listname>/DispForm.aspx*
```

None of these are working for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A related question (I know this was earlier, but just to connect them): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51266/site-collection-search-scope-exclude-rule-for-dispform-allitems-aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Rule to your scope to exclude all aspx files. Using the answer I posted here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/51338/2881

**Scope Rule Type:** Property Query

**Property Query:** FileExtension = aspx

**Behavior:** Require

---

In order to have the FileExtension property be available you will need to go to Search Administration within Central Administration and edit the FileExtension Managed Property *(**Search Administration** > **Metadata Properties** and find **FileExtension**)*. Check the box "**Allow this property to be used in scopes**" checkbox and click **OK**. Then run a full crawl.

Do yourself a favor and check that box for the ContentType managed property as well. Then you can add an additional Property Query rule that excludes folders by excluding ContentType = Folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to index a particular list, Mark **NO** to *"Allow items from this library to appear in search results"* in the list settings.

Or

The a dirty approach might be to modify the XSLT of the search results page to hide it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want the list to be searched and I have included only that in the scope, however I don't want allitems.aspx, dispform.aspx in the results. I know xslt can be modified, but looking at a easier approach

Answer (score 0):

By adding crawling rules using resgular expressions we can hide the system pages from the search results, do the following steps:

1. Go to Search Service Application: Manage Crawl Rules page and click on "**Crawl New Rule**"
2. Crawl New Rule page add path "*://*dispform.aspx*" and select the option "**Exclude all items in this path**" and check the "**Exclude complex URLs (URLs that contain question marks - ?)**" in **Crawl Configuration** section
3. Go to "**Index Reset**" and reset the search index
4. Go to **Content Source** page and "Start Full Crawl" for required Applicion

Search the appliction and the DispForm.aspx page disappers from the results page.