# Any way to only include a particular page (such as DispForm.aspx) in Search Results?

Tags: list, search, search-scope, display-form

I'm trying to create a search scope in SharePoint 2007 that searches all lists in a given site. But I want the results to only include the actual list item itself, not the all items form or anything else.

Except it seems that search scopes can only include/exclude items at the folder level. Is there any way I can create a simple search scope to only include the following:

http://*/DispForm.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your url is wrong, try this instead:

> http://< domain url>/* /*/DispForm.aspx

If i was to split it up it would be like this:

**url**

http://< domain url>

**parent folder levels (2)**

/* /*/

**the aspx file you want ;)**

DispForm.aspx

an example is:

> `http://portal.microsoft.com/*/*/DispForm.aspx`

Also you need to ammend or create a search rule within cental admin.

1) goto **central admin**

2) click on **Shared Services Administration**

3) click **Shared Services**

4) click **Search Settings**

5) click **New Crawl Rule**

6) add url parths you want to include/exclude from the crawl list :)

add the url above to the allow section and all other urls to disallow :)

hope it helps :)

Comment: I suppose this would work but I was hoping to accomplish it with a single scope, thus keeping the crawl index untouched. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following:

**Scope Rule Type:** Property Query

**Property Query:** FileExtension = aspx

**Behavior:** Require

---

In order to have the FileExtension property be available you will need to go to Search Administration within Central Administration and edit the FileExtension Managed Property *(**Search Administration** > **Metadata Properties** and find **FileExtension**)*. Check the box "**Allow this property to be used in scopes**" checkbox and click **OK**. Then run a full crawl.

Comment: Not seeing FileExtension in the properties list

Comment: @jethomas I forgot that this isn't available with the default managed property configuration. I've added instructions above on how to make this available for your scopes.